# Still cannot bind to my android service

Tags: android, binding, service, android-intent, data-transfer

I am quite new to Android and I am porting a C# program to android. Most of it is going fine but I have a long running problem of not being able to bind to 1 of my services.
I wanted to start and bind to the service to receive sendBroadcast(intent) from the service. The intent includes the data package for displaying in the UI using sendBroadcast(intent) but that returns a nullpointer, presumably because it is not connected to the activity properly.
I have followed so many different tutorials including the suggestions on this site all of which seemed fairly logical and were reported working.
Such as
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/bind-service-broadcast-receiver/
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/

The error appears to be that the service is not starting properly...see the stack trace below:
ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) line: 2943 
Service is null. onCreate or onStartCommand() do not get called in the service.

Unfortunately I cannot use handlers for this because the constructor of the Service class is not called from the activity.
As you can see I have tried many things and done some serious reading but obviously I am still missing something.
I will give you what version of code I am currently trying which produced the stack trace above. This code doesn’t buil past the activities oncreate()! BUT the bool tmp from bindservice() returns true??

The activity

```
        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // Various view initializations here

    Intent CuIntent = new Intent(this, Curve.class);
    CuIntent.setAction(".Core.CURVE_SERVICE");
    startService(CuIntent);
    Boolean tmp;
    tmp = bindService(CuIntent, CurveServiceConncetion, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


}

private ServiceConnection CurveServiceConncetion = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CurveService = ((LocalBinder<Curve>) service).getService();

    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CurveService = null;
    }
};
```

The activity manifest xml file with the service

```
        <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/pi_icon_t">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".BTUI" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <service android:name=".Core.Curve" />
</application>
```

The localBinder class (a separate class)is taken from another tutorial and is

```
    public class LocalBinder<S> extends Binder {
private String TAG = "LocalBinder";
private  WeakReference<S> mService;


public LocalBinder(S service){
    mService = new WeakReference<S>(service);
}


public S getService() {
    return mService.get();
}
```

}

The service looks like this

```
     public class Curve extends Service
{
    private IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder<Curve>(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String balls = "balls";
        Toast.makeText(this, "Curve Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;//
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
         String balls = "balls";
            Toast.makeText(this, "Curve Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

       mBinder = null;
    }
```

This really can't be that hard I hope someone can see where I am going wrong.

EDIT I picked a bad name for this post. The bind returns true but it crashes immediately after leaving the onCreate() of the activity. The error text is in the intro above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of code to look trough but I have an assumption:

Try to remove that:

```
CuIntent.setAction(".Core.CURVE_SERVICE");
```

And the intent filter from here:

```
<service android:name=".Core.Curve">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name=".Core.CURVE_SERVICE"></action>
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Hi Knickedi, Thanks for your suggestion but the same goes for Durga's answer, I have tried this :(

Comment: Woops pressed button. I have tried so many things and it seems that my service is not starting CurveService is null and the Curve class is never entered as I have stop points all over the place.

Comment: again wrong button, The binding returns true if I use the xml code as shown below but still CurveService  is null and my broadcastreceiver throws a null pointer

Comment: You can edit your question and your comments. Please don't abuse the comment section as chat (this gets really messy). So the bind works now, as you state it...

Comment: Sorry, I updated the xml code above and deleted some comments. Bind does work but then it throws the error ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) line: 2943 Service is null and it doesn't finish building – user960914

Comment: I found the problem. The constructor of the service had arguments and by following closer the errors (InstantiationException) and yet more reading, this was my problem. Unfortunately it opened another problem lol. Many thanks to those who tried to help